# Sorting values highest to lowest within a list

Tags: python, list, sorting

Python
At the moment my code prints this

```
Jem - 8
Rob - 9
Liah - 9
Zambia - 3
```

(name and score)
But how would I get this ordered highest to lowest? I researched and read something about Lambda but I am not too sure how it works?
I have a lot of code, by here is the sorting lines

```
for name in name_scores: #16
      print(name, '-', max(name_scores[name]))#17
```

It prints the highest score, which I would now like to sort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming your `name_scores` is a dict with keys being names, and values being a list of all their scores.

With this in mind, you can iterate over the sorted dict like so:

```
for name in sorted(name_scores, key=lambda x: max(name_scores[x]), reverse=True):
    print(name, '-', max(name_scores[name]))
```

`sorted()` takes an argument `key` which allows you to specify how you want the object sorted.  If you don't specify a `key` for a dict, then the sort will apply to the keys (which doesn't help us here).

So instead we can use the `key` to tell sorted what we want to sort by. A little magic is needed here in the form of a lambda.

`sorted()` iterates through your dict and one by one it calls the lambda to obtain a value.  The lambda's first argument (`x`) is supplied automatically and is a reference to the name at the time the lambda is called.  So the first time through it looks like this:

```
lambda x='Jem': max(name_scores[x])
```

This repeats for each name in your dict and those values retrieved are then used for the sort.

Comment: Thank you! That worked! I will accept the answer when it allows me(9mins)

Comment: Please could you explain what lamda does (in this context) and what x represents?

Answer (score 0):

If name_scores is a dict with names as keys and lists of scores as values such as:

```
name_scores = {'Jem':[8,4,5],'Rob':[9,1,5], 'Liah':[9], 'Zambia':[3]}
```

Then you can can get your required output by doing the following:

```
for name, scores in sorted(name_scores.items(),key=lambda x: max(x[1]), reverse=True):
    print(name,'-',max(scores))
```

How it works:

name_scores.items() produces a list of (name, scores) tuples.

lambda is used to define a function which returns the maximum score for each tuple.

Using sorted on a sequence with the key option will pass each item in the sequence to a function and sort by the value returned by the function. In this case we use sorted using the lambda function as a key.

If you are having trouble understanding the use of lambda functions it is often helpful to consider the following equivalent code without lambda functions:

```
def max_score(x):
    return max(x[1])

name_scores = {'Jem':[8,4,5],'Rob':[9,1,5], 'Liah':[9], 'Zambia':[3]}
for name, scores in sorted(name_scores.items(), key=max_score, reverse=True):
    print(name,'-',max(scores))
```